# How do you import different proc from openssl depending on the openssl version in nim?

Tags: openssl, dllimport, nim-lang

#### The Goal

I wanted to have a PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 hashing proc in nim and use the implementation provided by openssl for that. This shall work with **both** openssl 1 and openssl 3.

#### The Problem

As part of that process, I need to figure out the correct size the hash should have for the given hashing function. OpenSSL 3 provides those with a function called [`EVP_MD_get_size`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_MD_size.html).

If you only deal with openSSL3, you can just use:

```
from std/openssl import DLLSSLName, EVP_MD, EVP_sha256, DLLUtilName

proc EVP_MD_size_fixed*(md: EVP_MD): cint {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLUtilName, importc: "EVP_MD_get_size".}
```

That'll give you `EVP_MD_get_size` renamed to a proc called `EVP_MD_size_fixed`.

But if the openssl version is 1 and not 3 (e.g. because of debian), then the same proc is called `"EVP_MD_size"`, not `EVP_MD_get_size`. So you can't import it. You also can't just blindly import both `EVP_MD_size` and `EVP_MD_get_size` because it will throw a runtime error:

```
import std/[dynlib, openssl, strformat]

proc EVP_MD_size_fixed1*(md: EVP_MD): cint {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLUtilName, importc: "EVP_MD_get_size".}
proc EVP_MD_size_fixed2*(md: EVP_MD): cint {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLUtilName, importc: "EVP_MD_size".}

proc getOpenSSLMajorVersion(): uint =(getOpenSSLVersion() shr 28) and 0xF # Returns the major version of openssl

proc EVP_MD_size_fixed*(md: EVP_MD): cint =
  assert md != nil
  result =
    if getOpenSSLMajorVersion() == 3:
      EVP_MD_size_fixed1(md)
    elif getOpenSSLMajorVersion() == 1:
      EVP_MD_size_fixed2(md)
    else:
      raise newException(ValueError, fmt"This library supports only openssl 1 and 3. The openssl version we found was {getOpenSSLMajorVersion()}")


proc EVP_sha256_fixed(): EVP_MD    {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLUtilName, importc: "EVP_sha256".}
let digestFunction = EVP_sha256_fixed()

let hashLength: cint = EVP_MD_size_fixed(digestFunction)
echo hashLength
```

On a system with openssl3 leads to: `could not import: EVP_MD_size`

Now how do I make it so I call `EVP_MD_size` when the available openssl major version is 1 and `EVP_MD_get_size` when the available openssl major version is 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as provided by ElegantBeef and Yakoleb from the nim discord server is [std/dynlib](https://nim-lang.org/docs/dynlib.html). It allows loading a library at runtime, loading procs from it and calling them.

### The Code:

```
import std/[dynlib, openssl, strformat]

type DigestSizeProc = proc(md: EVP_MD): cint {.cdecl.}

proc getOpenSSLMajorVersion(): uint =(getOpenSSLVersion() shr 28) and 0xF # Returns the major version of openssl

# Load lib
let lib = loadLibPattern(DLLUtilName)
assert lib != nil, fmt"Could not find lib {DLLUtilName}"

# Load proc <-- HERE IS THE MAGIC
let evp_md_size_getter: DigestSizeProc = 
  if getOpenSSLMajorVersion() == 3:
    cast[DigestSizeProc](lib.symAddr("EVP_MD_get_size"))
  elif getOpenSSLMajorVersion() == 1:
    cast[DigestSizeProc](lib.symAddr("EVP_MD_size"))
  else:
    raise newException(ValueError, fmt"This library supports only openssl 1 and 3. The openssl version we found was {getOpenSSLMajorVersion()}")
assert evp_md_size_fixed != nil, fmt"Failed to load EVP_MD_size or EVP_MD_get_size proc from openssl version {getOpenSSLMajorVersion()}"

unloadLib(lib)

# Use proc
proc EVP_MD_size_fixed*(md: EVP_MD): cint =
  assert md != nil
  result = evp_md_size_getter(md)

proc EVP_sha256_fixed(): EVP_MD    {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLUtilName, importc: "EVP_sha256".}
let digestFunction: EVP_MD = EVP_sha256_fixed()

let hashLength: cint = EVP_MD_size_fixed(digestFunction)
echo hashLength
```

### Explanation:

#### Loading the library

As per the example there from std/dynlib, you can load a library using [`loadLib`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/dynlib.html#loadLib%2Cstring). In our case, we're using [`std/openssl.DLLUtilName`](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/e0328e28ee6b3fbfea812ffc2ce435ff76ccbc5a/lib/wrappers/openssl.nim#L45) as defined in the source-code there, so that'll return you a pattern of `libcrypto.so(.3|.1.1|.1.0.2|.1.0.1|.1.0.0|.0.9.9|.0.9.8|.48|.47|.46|.45|.44|.43|.41|.39|.38|.10|)`. That one requires [`loadLibPattern`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/dynlib.html#loadLibPattern%2Cstring) though, as this is not just a name of single library but a library-pattern.

#### Loading a proc from the library

We first need to know which name the proc has and which type that proc is. In this case, the name is either `EVP_MD_size` or `EVP_MD_get_size`. With that, we can use `lib.symAddr("<Symbol string>")` to get a pointer to the function. To be able to call it, we need to have nim interpret that pointer as a callable proc. So we'll have to cast it, but to which type?

We know the general type of that pointer, it's `proc(md: EVP_MD): cint` (As you can see from the [openssl docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_MD_size.html) where its defined `int EVP_MD_get_size(const EVP_MD *md);`

However, we also need to tell nim how to call the proc from openssl, the calling-convention . The one to use here is [cdecl](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-procedural-type), so the final type to cast that pointer to is
`type DigestSizeProc = proc(md: EVP_MD): cint {.cdecl.}`

Once we know all of that, we can just do a variable assignment as in the `Load proc` section.
Make sure to add asserts behind all the loading of libs/pointers to make sure you can easily figure out where Nil-pointer-access may occur.